# What's the most efficient way to set up an a remote desktop server with Linux?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-server, vnc

I need my Windows users to have a remote desktop (via RDP or VNC, I suppose, or maybe there's something better) on a Linux server to run desktop applications (the most important of which is a Win32 one, I hope it is going to work with WINE) remotely.

What direction should I better go digging? Can you recommend any good HOWTO?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest (although not easiest) way is to run Cygwin/X locally and start apps via SSH with X forwarding enabled. Invoking the apps can be done via batch files or shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Linux Terminal Server Project](http://www.ltsp.org/). I have no experience with it but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, possibly incorrectly that your users are sitting in from of the windows boxes and need access to some linux gui applications.

VNC works very nicely. Most Linux distributions have a the server sides vnc x-server included these days. Get a compatible windows vnc client and you should be good. If you need some additional security look for the ssl-enabled vnc stacks that are starting to crop up.

Getting a windows side xserver like the one in cygwin will also works but is more complicated and will be much harder to explain to windows users. If your users are already linux savy this won't be to bad, otherwise go with vnc.

Comment: "I'm assuming, possibly incorrectly that your users are sitting in from of the windows boxes and need access to some linux gui applications." - Actually users are indeed sitting in from of the windows boxes and need access to some *Windows* GUI applications run on the server side, but I haven't got a Window server and use Linux with Wine instead.

Comment: And the question also is what's faster. Bandwidth may vary and is normally near a megabit or two, some times half a megabit, never higher than 20 megabits.

Comment: Forwarded X is going to be faster than VNC, if you're bandwidth-constrained, in almost all circumstances.